# Knowing what server is chosen by a load balancer

Tags: networking, http

I am currently monitoring the logs of produced by our application server. But before I can do that, I would have to know which server's logs I would go to. To do this I do a tail of both logs and watch which of the logs "run" when I navigate to that page. If one of the logs run then I know which server I would go to for monitoring. This becomes complicated however, when both logs run at the same when I key in the the url of the application. When that happens what I do is login and then after logging in, I stop both logs and read my login name in both of them. Only then will I know which server I am using.

Is there an easier way to do this? Maybe I can use a packet sniffer like wireshark or something. Our application is both accessible on the public web as well as the intranet.

Answer (score 3):

I often just stick some commented text into the HTML that includes the local server name or at least identifies it without necessarily having the hostname, then check for it when loading the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can let the load balancer add a header, preferably not a real hostname, but one that would allow you to understand which server it is.